# multiple columns with two foreign key column in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three tables:

**1.**

```
    @Table(name = "VRTL_PI_BOI_DLVR")
    VrtlPiBoiDlvr
    private List<VrtlPiBoiDlvrActions> vrtlPiBoiDlvrActions;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vrtlPiBoiDlvr", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @Cache(region = "business", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    public List<VrtlPiBoiDlvrActions> getVrtlPiBoiDlvrActions() {
        return vrtlPiBoiDlvrActions;
    }
    public void setVrtlPiBoiDlvrActions(
            List<VrtlPiBoiDlvrActions> vrtlPiBoiDlvrActions) {
        this.vrtlPiBoiDlvrActions = vrtlPiBoiDlvrActions;
    }
```

**2.**

```
@Table(name = "VRTL_PI_BOI_DLVR_ACTIONS")
VrtlPiBoiDlvrActions

private List<VrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn> vrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn;

private VrtlPiBoiDlvr vrtlPiBoiDlvr;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "vrtlPiBoiDlvrActions", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@Cache(region = "business", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public List<VrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn> getVrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn() {
    return vrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn;
}




public void setVrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn(List<VrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn> vrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn) {
    this.vrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn = vrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn;
}


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "BOI_DLVR_ID", referencedColumnName = "BOI_DLVR_ID", nullable = false)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
public VrtlPiBoiDlvr getVrtlPiBoiDlvr() {
    return vrtlPiBoiDlvr;
}


public void setVrtlPiBoiDlvr(VrtlPiBoiDlvr vrtlPiBoiDlvr) {
    this.vrtlPiBoiDlvr = vrtlPiBoiDlvr;
}
```

**3.**

```
@Table(name = "VRTL_PI_BOI_DLVR_IFN")
VrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn

private VrtlPiBoiDlvrActions vrtlPiBoiDlvrActions;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "ACTION_ID", referencedColumnName = "ACTION_ID", nullable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOI_DLVR_ID", referencedColumnName = "BOI_DLVR_ID", nullable = false)})
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    public VrtlPiBoiDlvrActions getVrtlPiBoiDlvrActions(){
        return vrtlPiBoiDlvrActions;
    }
```

The exception is :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name boi_dlvr_id in table VRTL_PI_BOI_DLVR_ACTIONS
```

What do I have to change to fix this?

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Reformat it to have the code in code blocks. And the error message is pretty clear. What don't you understand about it?

Comment: how i get BOI_DLVR_ID in table VrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn when its f.k in table VrtlPiBoiDlvrActions and p.k in table VrtlPiBoiDlvr

Comment: You mapped getVrtlPiBoiDlvr() to the column named BOI_DLVR_ID. And this column doesn't exist in the table. So, what do you expect?

Comment: I did not mention it , BOI_DLVR_ID exist in VrtlPiBoiDlvr

Comment: Read the error message: "Unable to find column with logical name boi_dlvr_id in table **VRTL_PI_BOI_DLVR_ACTIONS**".

Comment: i know , that's is the problem in VRTL_PI_BOI_DLVR_ACTIONS BOI_DLVR_ID  is f.k to BOI_DLVR_ID in VrtlPiBoiDlvr and VrtlPiBoiDlvrIfn is acollection of entity in VRTL_PI_BOI_DLVR_ACTIONS  (i know how to get actionId thet is p.k in VRTL_PI_BOI_DLVR_ACTIONS but i dont know how to get BOI_DLVR_ID

Comment: You don't need to "get" anything. You need to add the missing column to the table. You must add a column named boi_dlvr_id to the table VRTL_PI_BOI_DLVR_ACTIONS. I don't know how I can make it clearer.